# Office365 synchronize calendars (deletion case)

Tags: java, outlook, calendar, office365, office365api

I want to synchronize the calendars that I have in Office365 using Push Notifications and REST API that are provided by Microsoft. They have very useful API, but for events:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/office365/howto/sync-calendar-view

It allows to get only the thing that were changed since the last synchronization. 
The problem is that I haven't found something similar, but for the calendars. That's why at the beginning I just pull all the calendars and save them, and then I listen to push notifications for this resource:
"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars"
Once I get a push notification I can retrieve an ID of the changed calendar and then get it via REST. However, if calendar is deleted then I don't know which one was deleted since it can't be retrieved from Office365 anymore.

If we had this synchronization, I would expect us having the response like with events: reason: deleted, reasondId: calendarId.

To sum up, the question is whether there is sync approaches for calendars, and if there aren't, how to handle delete notification so that I know what calendar Id is.